# End here document anywhere

Tags: shell, here-document

As title suggests, is it possible to end a here document anywhere, and not only on a new line?

Usually heredocs are used as follow:

```
$ cat << 'EOF'
First line
  Seconde line
EOF
```

And the output would be:

```
First line
  Seconde line
```

Is there a way to stop reading with the delimiter being at the end of the line? That would allow me to do something like:

```
$ cat << 'EOF'
First line
  Seconde lineEOF
```

Comment: ```````no```````

Comment: The syntax explicitly states the EOF has to be in a line by itself, without any whitespace. Even an invisible \r on the end will stop it being recognised.

Comment: ... the one exception being *leading tabs*, **if** the `<<-` form is used

Comment: If you want just to omit the terminating newline, use `awk -v ORS= 'BEGIN{if(getline>0)print}{print RS$0}' <<'EOF'` ... `EOF` instead of `cat`.

Comment: @kaligne If you did what you suggest then the contents of the here document wouldn't be a valid text "file" per POSIX as it wouldn't have a terminating newline and so then YMMV with what any tool might do with that string. If you tell us what you're trying to do with a multi-line string with no terminating newline like that then we can probably help you do whatever that is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could think of would be something like this:

```
text=$(cat << EOF
line 1\x0a\
line 2\x0a\
line 3
EOF
)
echo -en $text
```

or even shorter

```
echo -en "$(cat << EOF
line 1
line 2
line 3
EOF
)"
```